# Git Seems to Have Commit From Remote Pull, But Log Does Not Show Commit

Tags: git

After doing a pull from a remote repo, my local repo is in a strange state.

`git log` does not show the commits from the remote repo. The files that should be changed are unchanged. `git status` shows that I'm on `branch master` (as expected) with a clean working directory. In other words, can't find any evidence from the pull.

But, if I `git show` a specific commit from the remote, the correct changes for that commit are shown. How can `git show` be working correctly, but my repo be unchanged and the `log` not displaying the commit?

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably those commits where fetched (as part of a previous `git pull` that you aborted or reverted), but not applied to the local `master`.

Comment: Are those commits somewhere in HEAD/working tree/index? And how can those commits be applied to the local master?

Comment: You can try to merge things from `origin/master` with `git merge origin/master`, but the result really depends on your specific situation: have `master` (your "local view" of that branch) and `origin/master` (a pointer to master branch as it is on the remote repository) diverged? I.e. did you commit any changeset to your `master`?

Comment: To answer your first question, most likely those commits are in `git log origin/master`.

Comment: Changes were committed my local master, and also pushed to the remote master. I tried a `git merge origin/master`, but it as `Already up-to-date.` `git log origin/master` shows the same log as `git log master`. So basically, these commits are no longer indexed on my local repo, but they are sitting in the .git folder and can be accessed using `git show MISSINGCOMMIT`?

Comment: Try with `git branch -a --contains $COMMIT`, it will tell you which branches (local and remote) contain your commit. If there is no output, it's possible that these commits were referenced some time in the past, but now they are not linked to any branch anymore (so they will be removed the next time that git does internal cleaning of dangling commits). If this is the case, and if you want to apply them manually to the current branch, try `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: Ah, that last comment nails it for me! That shows that the commit is in remotes/origin/randombranch, which answers all my questions about what's going on with it. And your clarification about dangling commits is correct, too. Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your git pull failed and you reset hard. This means you are back to where you were. But part of git pull is git fetch. So you actually got the objects contained in the remote's branch. To test you could take a look at

```
git log origin/master
```

if this does not show them, do a

```
git fetch
```

which should just update remote tracking branches. To see exactly what's on the remote you can

```
git ls-remote origin
```

(assuming origin is the name of the remote in question)

remember that `git pull` is the combination of `git fetch` and `git merge` (or `git rebase` if you configured it that way).